# ng-repeat - Is it possible to store result of function call?

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code:

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="term in Items | filter:searchText track by term.Element">
                        <tr class="term-row">

                            <td ng-show="!IsValid(term)" class="text-center">
                                <img ng-show="GetStatus(term)==''" src='@Url.Content("~/Lib/img/spinner26x26.gif")' />
                                <span class="label label-danger">Invalid</span>
                            </td>
                            <td ng-show="IsValid(term)" class="text-center">
                                <img ng-show="GetStatus(term)==''" src='@Url.Content("~/Lib/img/spinner26x26.gif")' />
                                <span class="label label-success" ng-bind="GetStatus(term)"></span>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
```

As you can see I have IsValid(item) called in several places while iterating through the repeater. Is it possible to have the result of that method stored in a local for the repeater variable and then to use the result instead of calling the function x times?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to have ng-repeat in the <tr> tag rather than <tbody> first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

```
<tbody ng-repeat="term in Items | filter:searchText track by term.Element" ng-init="isValid = IsValid(term)">
```

Then use that value

```
<td ng-show="!isValid" class="text-center">
<td ng-show="isValid" class="text-center">
```

Comment: great! I tried to add the result of the other function  ng-init="isValid = IsValid(term); status = GetStatus(term)" but didn't work. Is there anything more specific if I want to use two functions?

Comment: this should work too.. can you provide a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: I think is not working because the calculation of GetStatus is happening on later stage, when a result of service call is done... That's why I have GetStatus(term)=='' - initially when the data is still not retrieved and then this is changed once the data is present and showing the actual status. It will be too complicated to create an example which you can explore...